# How can I split, debounce and join streams?

Tags: rust, stream

I'm struggling a bit to understand the infrastructure around `futures::streams`.

Suppose I have a stream of `u8` items. I'd like to *convert* it into a stream of `Event` items, in which:

```rust
enum Event {
  Short(u8),
  Long(u8),
}
```

My resulting stream should emit `Event::Short(x)` whenever the underlying stream emits `x`. It should **also** emit `Event::Long(x)` whenever the underlying stream hasn't changed its `x` value for `N` seconds.

The conceptual steps would be:

1. Split the stream into stream `a` and `b`
2. Apply debouncing on stream `b`, making it emit `x` only when `x` hasn't changed for `N` seconds.
3. Join the two streams.

I believe join would be handled by [`select`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.29/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.select). But how can I split the original stream into two, given its items are `Copy`? And is there such a utility like a debouncing mechanism, either in `futures` or `tokio`?

Answer (score 2):

It may not be exactly what you wanted but this does something like what you asked for.

```
use {
    futures::{
        prelude::*,
        Async, Poll,
        stream::{
            Stream, Fuse,
        },
        sync::mpsc,
    },
    std::{
        thread,
        time::{Duration, Instant},
    }
};

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Event<T> {
    Short(T),
    Long(T),
}


#[derive(Debug)]
struct Debounce<S: Stream> {
    stream: Fuse<S>,
    debouncetime: Duration,
    timestamp: Instant,
    last: S::Item,
    emitted: bool,
}

impl<S> Debounce<S>
    where S: Stream, S::Item: Copy + Default + PartialEq {
    fn new(s: S) -> Self {
        Self{
            stream: s.fuse(),
            debouncetime: Duration::from_millis(2300),
            timestamp: Instant::now(),
            last: Default::default(),
            emitted: true,
        }
    }
}

impl<S> Stream for Debounce<S>
    where S: Stream, S::Item: Copy + Default + PartialEq
{
    type Item = Event<S::Item>;
    type Error = S::Error;

    fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<Option<Event<S::Item>>, S::Error> {
        if !self.emitted && self.timestamp.elapsed() >= self.debouncetime {
            self.emitted = true;
            return Ok(Some(Event::Long(self.last)).into())
        }

        match self.stream.poll()? {
            Async::Ready(Some(item)) => {
                if item != self.last {
                    self.last = item;
                    self.timestamp = Instant::now();
                    self.emitted = false;
                }

                Ok(Some(Event::Short(item)).into())
            }
            Async::Ready(None) => Ok(None.into()),
            Async::NotReady => Ok(Async::NotReady)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let (mut tx, rx) = mpsc::channel(1);

    thread::spawn(move || {
        for i in vec![1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7] {
            tx = tx.send(i).wait().unwrap();
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
        }
    });
    let result = Debounce::new(rx).collect().wait();

    dbg!(result.unwrap());
}
```

Comment: This gets very close indeed. It definitely helps me figure out how things actually work, so thanks! I was hoping to see an answer using combinator functions, yet had a feeling `impl Stream` would be the solution.